# VBA macro to split data in multiple worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

*Before you say this is a duplicate, please see below.*

**TL:DR**
There is a table with data on Sheet1 and a similar table on Sheet2.

The table on each sheet has data with one column being a key with multiple records associated with it (like same zip code).

I need to split the data into sheets by id value (like zip code) such that I end up with a separate Excel file for each id value, where each of these files will have 2 sheets.

*Sheet1* will have the rows from Sheet1 on the source file that are associated with the corresponding id value.

*Sheet2* will have the rows from Sheet2 on the source file for the same id value.

**Details:**

The **macro below** splits the rows by column values, where column "D" identifies multiple records by same value, such as zip code.

What I need is to be able to replicate the same subset-and-copy process for more than one worksheet on the source file e.g. Test1 and Test2. The goal is to output subsets of the data on each worksheet into similarly named and formatted worksheets on multiple files.

It is important to retain any formatting such as any rows above header row (which does not start at row 1), column widths and colors, autofilter, and sheet zoom. I believe i can get that worked out once the basic code that does the splitting is figured out.

The **output file** names would contain the id value (e.g. zip code) followed by "testfile.xlsx". Each of the output files would have two worksheets, Test1 and Test2.

Each worksheet would replicate the structure as far as column headers and formatting as on the corresponding source worksheet, but would only contain the rows associated with the id value which is being split out into the given file.

Assume just two worksheets for now, Test1 and Test2 (once this is done, I can replicate to add more if needed). Also assume that both sheets on the source file contain the same list of id values in the key column D, but the count of rows associated with the same id value varies across worksheets.

Finally, assume same layout on both Test1 and Test2, though in reality these may be different, e.g. the id column (column D) on Test1 may be another column (column C) on Test2.

As I mentioned, **the code below does the job for a single worksheet.** What I need is to replicate this processing so it works for several worksheets. I am guessing it is a relatively straight-forward tweak but could use some help figuring out how to get it to work.

I had a *similar* question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101474/vba-macro-which-filters-and-splits-dataset-into-new-workbooks) which copied some additional static worksheets. However the difference is that in this case the additional worksheets also need to be split by the key value. I am newbie to VBA so need clear how-to and code sample with annotation. Would appreciate your help!

```
Sub parse_by_id()

Dim r As Long, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Test1") 'Sheet1
    Sheets.Add().Name = "temp"
    .Range("D12", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("temp").Range("D12"), Unique:=True
     For Each rng In Sheets("temp").Range("D13", Sheets("temp").Range("D13").End(xlDown))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("D12").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=rng 'field:=3
        Set ws = Sheets.Add

        lastRow = .Range("B12:F12").End(xlDown).Row 
        .Range("B12:bi" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
        ws.Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        ws.Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .Range("B2:bi11").Copy ws.Range("B2")   
        Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 1

        For r = 1 To lastRow
            ws.Rows(r).RowHeight = .Rows(r).RowHeight
        Next r

        ws.Range("B3:F3").MergeCells = True 
        ws.Name = rng
        ws.Move
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Rows.Hidden = False
        Columns.Hidden = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        Range("D13").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 95 
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="C:\TEMP\" & rng & "-testfile.xlsx"
    Next rng
      Sheets("temp").Delete
End With
```

Comment: So this is going through every cell in `D12:D<endrow>`, autofiltering for your `rng.value`, copying that to a new worksheet, moving that a new workbook. After the `ws.move` do a `Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook` to capture that thing to a variable, autofilter your second sheet for `rng.value` just the same, create a new worksheet in `newWB` `Set newWS = newWB.Worksheets.Add` and copy/paste your autofiltered values. Then save up and all that stuff. Should be a relatively simple add doing it that way.

Comment: @JNevill Appreciate the helpful tip, it turned out a bit trickier but getting close. Thanks!